# Making CollectionView Show Cells Using Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uistoryboard

**ISSUE**: *Cells in Collection View Not Displaying When Entered In Storyboard*

I have been following tutorials and can currently insert preloaded cells into a scene using Swift:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

   var NumTitles = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
   var SubTitles = ["greeting", "friends", "shopping", "date?"]

   //viewDidLoad() & didReceiveMemoryWarning() functions

   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
     { return NumTitles.count }

   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

     let NumTitle = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
     NumTitle.text = NumTitles[indexPath.row]
     let Subtitle = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
     Subtitle.text = SubTitles[indexPath.row]

     return cell }}
```

[image: Result of Running (Right) based on Storyboard (left)]

Is there a way I can do this using JUST the storyboard? Without the script, it will not display any of the cells, (including the first one, which is admittedly the only one in the visual when I took the screen shot)

I would like to do it in storyboard specifically because when any of these is clicked, it will redirect to its own page with another collection view, and I do not know of any simple way of programming/organizing it without storyboard.

Comment: The cell present in the storyboard inside the collection view is just a prototype cell. Collection View uses its datasource methods to create the cell. So there is no direct way to make it using the storyboard only. You have to implement its data source methods to make it work.

Comment: Thanks. After I started researching more, I figured it out.